# Divide the screen into SurfaceView and xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview

`MyActivity` has `setContentView(MySurfaceView)` that covers all the screen.

I would like to divide the screen into two parts: the first **2/3** of the screen must be occupied by `MySurfaceView` and the last **1/3** by `my_activity_layout.xml`.

How can I do that? Thanks.

[image]

**EDIT**

Thanks for your answers, but I don't have how to apply them in my case. To be clear, these are my objects:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

To attach an **xml** file in your layout, you can make use of the `<include>` tag.

Reusing layouts is particularly powerful as it allows you create reusable complex layouts. For example, a yes/no button panel, or custom progress bar with description text. [More](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts)

You can have a functionality as shown in the question with the help of `ConstraintLayout`. Of course, there are solutions using the legacy `<LinearLayout>` with something called as **weights** but as the warning says **Weights are bad for performance**.

**Why weights are bad for performance?**

> Layout weights require a widget to be measured twice. When a LinearLayout with non-zero weights is nested inside another LinearLayout with non-zero weights, then the number of measurements increase exponentially.

So let's get on to the solution using `<ConstraintLayout>`.

Let's say we have a layout file called `my_activity_layout.xml` and we use the below code to achieve what we want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.67" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/news_title"
        layout="@layout/my_activity_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see the `Guideline` help us to get 2/3 i.e 66.666 ~ 67 % of the screen, and then you can constraint your `SurfaceView` and your layout using `<include>` tag on your activity.

You can also see the required result:

[image: Desired Result]

You can just copy-paste the solution and see if it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to apply your solution to my case :( I have edited my question to make my situation more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with a linear Layout and specifying a layout weight for the correction ratios.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

    <include layout="my_activity_layout.xml" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Swap the weights.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to apply your solution to my case :( I have edited my question to make my situation more clear.