# Not able to populate a custom view ( totally java based ) in a line layout ( Xml based )

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I have a custom view which is totally Java based ( no XML ) code is below and i want to add this inside a new XML based layout ..Please guide how to do this however i also want that when it get displayed the screen will show 50 % xml layout and 50 % customview is it even possible ? please see below picture for more clarity

[image]

follows is the Java code of the animation :

```
public class AccelerometerPlayActivity extends Activity {

private SimulationView mSimulationView;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private PowerManager mPowerManager;
private WindowManager mWindowManager;
private Display mDisplay;
private WakeLock mWakeLock;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get an instance of the SensorManager
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

    // Get an instance of the PowerManager
    mPowerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);

    // Get an instance of the WindowManager
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mDisplay = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

    // Create a bright wake lock
    mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, getClass()
            .getName());

    // instantiate our simulation view and set it as the activity's content
    mSimulationView = new SimulationView(this);
    mSimulationView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wood);
    setContentView(mSimulationView);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    /*
     * when the activity is resumed, we acquire a wake-lock so that the
     * screen stays on, since the user will likely not be fiddling with the
     * screen or buttons.
     */
    mWakeLock.acquire();

    // Start the simulation
    mSimulationView.startSimulation();

     mSimulationView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(700, 300));

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    /*
     * When the activity is paused, we make sure to stop the simulation,
     * release our sensor resources and wake locks
     */

    // Stop the simulation
    mSimulationView.stopSimulation();

    // and release our wake-lock
    mWakeLock.release();
}

class SimulationView extends LinearLayout implements SensorEventListener {
    // diameter of the balls in meters
    private static final float sBallDiameter = 0.004f;
    private static final float sBallDiameter2 = sBallDiameter * sBallDiameter;

    private final int mDstWidth;
    private final int mDstHeight;

    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private long mLastT;

    private float mXDpi;
    private float mYDpi;
    private float mMetersToPixelsX;
    private float mMetersToPixelsY;
    private float mXOrigin;
    private float mYOrigin;
    private float mSensorX;
    private float mSensorY;
    private float mHorizontalBound;
    private float mVerticalBound;
    private final ParticleSystem mParticleSystem;
    /*
     * Each of our particle holds its previous and current position, its
     * acceleration. for added realism each particle has its own friction
     * coefficient.
     */
    class Particle extends View {
        private float mPosX = (float) Math.random();
        private float mPosY = (float) Math.random();
        private float mVelX;
        private float mVelY;

        public Particle(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public Particle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public Particle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        public Particle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr,
                        int defStyleRes) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        }

        public void computePhysics(float sx, float sy, float dT) {

            final float ax = -sx/5;
            final float ay = -sy/5;

            mPosX += mVelX * dT + ax * dT * dT / 2;
            mPosY += mVelY * dT + ay * dT * dT / 2;

            mVelX += ax * dT;
            mVelY += ay * dT;
        }

        /*
         * Resolving constraints and collisions with the Verlet integrator
         * can be very simple, we simply need to move a colliding or
         * constrained particle in such way that the constraint is
         * satisfied.
         */
        public void resolveCollisionWithBounds() {
            final float xmax = mHorizontalBound;
            final float ymax = mVerticalBound;
            final float x = mPosX;
            final float y = mPosY;
            if (x > xmax) {
                mPosX = xmax;
                mVelX = 0;
            } else if (x < -xmax) {
                mPosX = -xmax;
                mVelX = 0;
            }
            if (y > ymax) {
                mPosY = ymax;
                mVelY = 0;
            } else if (y < -ymax) {
                mPosY = -ymax;
                mVelY = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * A particle system is just a collection of particles
     */
    class ParticleSystem {
        static final int NUM_PARTICLES = 5;
        private Particle mBalls[] = new Particle[NUM_PARTICLES];

        ParticleSystem() {
            /*
             * Initially our particles have no speed or acceleration
             */
            for (int i = 0; i < mBalls.length; i++) {
                mBalls[i] = new Particle(getContext());
                mBalls[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ball);
                mBalls[i].setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
                addView(mBalls[i], new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(mDstWidth, mDstHeight));
            }
        }

        /*
         * Update the position of each particle in the system using the
         * Verlet integrator.
         */
        private void updatePositions(float sx, float sy, long timestamp) {
            final long t = timestamp;
            if (mLastT != 0) {
                final float dT = (float) (t - mLastT) / 1000.f /** (1.0f / 1000000000.0f)*/;
                    final int count = mBalls.length;
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        Particle ball = mBalls[i];
                        ball.computePhysics(sx, sy, dT);
                    }
            }
            mLastT = t;
        }

        /*
         * Performs one iteration of the simulation. First updating the
         * position of all the particles and resolving the constraints and
         * collisions.
         */
        public void update(float sx, float sy, long now) {
            // update the system's positions
            updatePositions(sx, sy, now);

            // We do no more than a limited number of iterations
            final int NUM_MAX_ITERATIONS = 1;

            /*
             * Resolve collisions, each particle is tested against every
             * other particle for collision. If a collision is detected the
             * particle is moved away using a virtual spring of infinite
             * stiffness.
             */
            boolean more = true;
            final int count = mBalls.length;
            for (int k = 0; k < NUM_MAX_ITERATIONS && more; k++) {
                more = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    Particle curr = mBalls[i];
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < count; j++) {
                        Particle ball = mBalls[j];
                        float dx = ball.mPosX - curr.mPosX;
                        float dy = ball.mPosY - curr.mPosY;
                        float dd = dx * dx + dy * dy;
                        // Check for collisions
                        if (dd <= sBallDiameter2) {
                            /*
                             * add a little bit of entropy, after nothing is
                             * perfect in the universe.
                             */
                            dx += ((float) Math.random() - 0.5f) * 0.0001f;
                            dy += ((float) Math.random() - 0.5f) * 0.0001f;
                            dd = dx * dx + dy * dy;
                            // simulate the spring
                            final float d = (float) Math.sqrt(dd);
                            final float c = (0.5f * (sBallDiameter - d)) / d;
                            final float effectX = dx * c;
                            final float effectY = dy * c;
                            curr.mPosX -= effectX;
                            curr.mPosY -= effectY;
                            ball.mPosX += effectX;
                            ball.mPosY += effectY;
                            more = true;
                        }
                    }
                    curr.resolveCollisionWithBounds();
                }
            }
        }

        public int getParticleCount() {
            return mBalls.length;
        }

        public float getPosX(int i) {
            return mBalls[i].mPosX;
        }

        public float getPosY(int i) {
            return mBalls[i].mPosY;
        }
    }

    public void startSimulation() {
        /*
         * It is not necessary to get accelerometer events at a very high
         * rate, by using a slower rate (SENSOR_DELAY_UI), we get an
         * automatic low-pass filter, which "extracts" the gravity component
         * of the acceleration. As an added benefit, we use less power and
         * CPU resources.
         */
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    public void stopSimulation() {
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    public SimulationView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        mXDpi = metrics.xdpi;
        mYDpi = metrics.ydpi;
        mMetersToPixelsX = mXDpi / 0.0254f;
        mMetersToPixelsY = mYDpi / 0.0254f;

        // rescale the ball so it's about 0.5 cm on screen
        mDstWidth = (int) (sBallDiameter * mMetersToPixelsX + 0.5f);
        mDstHeight = (int) (sBallDiameter * mMetersToPixelsY + 0.5f);
        mParticleSystem = new ParticleSystem();

        Options opts = new Options();
        opts.inDither = true;
        opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        // compute the origin of the screen relative to the origin of
        // the bitmap
        mXOrigin = (w - mDstWidth) * 0.5f;   //@nyy this is changing the rect of balls to simulate
        mYOrigin = (h - mDstHeight) * 0.5f;
        mHorizontalBound = ((w / mMetersToPixelsX - sBallDiameter) * 0.5f);//@nyy this is changing the rect of balls to simulate
        mVerticalBound = ((h / mMetersToPixelsY - sBallDiameter) * 0.5f);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() != Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
            return;
        /*
         * record the accelerometer data, the event's timestamp as well as
         * the current time. The latter is needed so we can calculate the
         * "present" time during rendering. In this application, we need to
         * take into account how the screen is rotated with respect to the
         * sensors (which always return data in a coordinate space aligned
         * to with the screen in its native orientation).
         */

        switch (mDisplay.getRotation()) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                mSensorX = event.values[0];
                mSensorY = event.values[1];
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                mSensorX = -event.values[1];
                mSensorY = event.values[0];
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                mSensorX = -event.values[0];
                mSensorY = -event.values[1];
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                mSensorX = event.values[1];
                mSensorY = -event.values[0];
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        /*
         * Compute the new position of our object, based on accelerometer
         * data and present time.
         */
        final ParticleSystem particleSystem = mParticleSystem;
        final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final float sx = mSensorX;
        final float sy = mSensorY;

        particleSystem.update(sx, sy, now);

        final float xc = mXOrigin;
        final float yc = mYOrigin;
        final float xs = mMetersToPixelsX;
        final float ys = mMetersToPixelsY;
        final int count = particleSystem.getParticleCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            /*
             * We transform the canvas so that the coordinate system matches
             * the sensors coordinate system with the origin in the center
             * of the screen and the unit is the meter.
             */
            final float x = xc + particleSystem.getPosX(i) * xs;
            final float y = yc - particleSystem.getPosY(i) * ys;
            particleSystem.mBalls[i].setTranslationX(x);
            particleSystem.mBalls[i].setTranslationY(y);
        }

        // and make sure to redraw asap
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I have found this but the issue is not yet resolved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53106904/divide-the-screen-into-surfaceview-and-xml-layout

Comment: Let me know if i understand you correctly. You want a custom view that draws a background and a list of particles and you want to add this custom view inside a linear layout?

Comment: Yes @Mihai thats correct  My custom view is totally Java based ( not XML ) and its creating few particles and i want to add this inside XML based layout ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are just setting setContentView(mSimulationView) to mSimulationView only.
you have include all content that is custom layout and linearlayout in xml file.

```
 setContentView(R.layout.your_xml)
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly then you don't need to override the linearLayout your simulation view would look like this.

```
class SimulationView extends View implements SensorEventListener, ParticleSystemListener {
    private final ParticleSystem mParticleSystem;
    /* all your normal initialization */

    public SimulationView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    /* all your normal initialization */
        mParticleSystem = new mParticleSystem(this); // initialize the system here whatever resources you need for your particles if you use bitmaps you can pass a bitmap here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
       // we notify the particleSystem that the size has changed so i can adjust it's bounds
       mParticleSystem.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        /* all your normal code */
        mParticleSystem.updatePositions(x, y, time)
    }

    @Override
    public void needNewFrame(){
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        /* draw your background or just call super witch will draw it for you */
        mParticleSystem.drawAllParticles(canvas);
    }
}
```

Create an interface to to get notified when we particle system wants to draw a new frame or simply pass the view and call invalidate on it;

```
interface ParticleSystemListener {
    public void needNewFrame();
}
```

Your particleSystem should do all the computation and handle adding and removing particles as well as passing the dway command down to the particles.

```
class ParticleSystem {
    private float mParticleSystemListener;
    private Particle mBalls[] = new Particle[NUM_PARTICLES];
    private Rect mBounds = new Rect();

    public ParticleSystem (ParticleSystemListener listener) {
        mParticleSystemListener = listener;
        /* all your normal initialization */
    }

    // our particle system keeps track of the bounds in which it draws the particles and tells the particles when it has changed
    public void setBounds(left, top, right, bottom){
        mBounds.left = left;
        mBounds.top = top;
        mBounds.right = right;
        mBounds.bottom = bottom;
        for(ball : mBalls){
           ball.boundsChanged();
        }
        // after we computed new positions is time to refresh the view
        mParticleSystemListener.needNewFrame();
    }

    private void updatePositions(float sx, float sy, long timestamp){
        /* all your normal computation*/
        for(ball : mBalls){
         ball.computePhysics(sx, sy, dT);
        }

        // after we computed new positions is time to refresh the view
        mParticleSystemListener.needNewFrame();
    }

    // the view wants us to draw on this canvas so we just pass the canvas to the particles
    public void drawAllParticles(canvas){
        for(ball : mBalls){
            ball.draw(canvas);
        }
    }

}
```

All the state is gonna reside in the particle class. the particle class should know its position and how to draw itself

```
class Particle {
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Bitmap mSprite;
    private Rect mBounds;

    public Particle(Rect bounds) {
       mBounds = bounds;
    /* initialize your paint here or get a bitmap passed in */
    }

    public void computePhysics(float sx, float sy, float dT);

    public void boundsChanged(){
    // move your particle since the bounds have changed
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y ,r, paint); // draw a circle at position
        or 
        canvas.drawBitmap(mSprite,  float left, float top, some paint or null) // draw a sprite
    }
}
```

As you can see this is not the full implementation i didn't check if you calculate the accelerations and positions correctly this is just un overview of how your classes should look and never create objects inside your onDraw() loop. Inside onDraw() should live only code that is necessary for drawing. Handle All your calculations outside onDraw and when ready for a new frame call invalidate(). Or if you need even more performance you can override SurfaceView or TextureView.

Answer (score 0):

Ok FInally i figured it out it was a very very simple solution however it took me 4 days of continuous googling and sample code reading trying to make sense of similar kind of apps 
i got the idea from Adam Porter code for sensors and finally got this

Objective was to show the above attached Java ( dynamic view code ) where NO xml was ever involved however i want to run that code via XML by setting so that i can limit it in a small frame or layout instead of whole screen

follows are the steps i did

in XML file
1, create an XML file named :dyn under layouts 
2, added a frame layout in that XML file with ID : fl  ( framelayout)
and in my java file : 
1, set the content to R.layout.dyn instead of previously set as msimulationview
2, created a java framelayout called jfl and then linked it with xml based framelayout called fl 
3, added the view( msimulation view ) to the java based framelayout i.e. Jfl

follows is the code it just took 3 lines to achieve that ... 
thanks for every one who took their time helping out this

[image]

follows is the code :

```
    setContentView( R.layout.dyn);
    FrameLayout jfl = findViewById( R.id.fl );
    mSimulationView.setId( R.id.fl );
        jfl.getContext();
        jfl.addView( mSimulationView );
```

THanks a lot every one.

here is the complete Java file :

```
package com.example.sensormanager;



import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.zip.Inflater;


public class acceleromparticles extends Activity {

    public SimulationView mSimulationView;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private PowerManager mPowerManager;
    private WindowManager mWindowManager;
    private Display mDisplay;
    private WakeLock mWakeLock;
    public int  ui = 1 ;
    public FrameLayout fl;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get an instance of the SensorManager
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        // Get an instance of the PowerManager
        mPowerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);

        // Get an instance of the WindowManager
        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mDisplay = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
        mSimulationView = new SimulationView(getApplicationContext());

        //    fl.addView( mSimulationView );
        setContentView( R.layout.dyn);
        FrameLayout jfl = findViewById( R.id.fl );
        jfl.addView( mSimulationView );
       mSimulationView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wood);
       // setContentView(mSimulationView);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        /*
         * when the activity is resumed, we acquire a wake-lock so that the
         * screen stays on, since the user will likely not be fiddling with the
         * screen or buttons.
         */
        //mWakeLock.acquire();

        // Start the simulation
        mSimulationView.startSimulation();
        // mSimulationView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(700, 300));

    }



    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        /*
         * When the activity is paused, we make sure to stop the simulation,
         * release our sensor resources and wake locks
         */

        // Stop the simulation
        mSimulationView.stopSimulation();
        // and release our wake-lock
        // mWakeLock.release();
    }

    class SimulationView extends FrameLayout implements SensorEventListener {
        // diameter of the balls in meters
        private static final float sBallDiameter = 0.0005f;
        private static final float sBallDiameter2 = sBallDiameter * sBallDiameter;
        private final int mDstWidth;
        private final int mDstHeight;
        private Sensor mAccelerometer;
        private long mLastT;
        private float mXDpi;
        private float mYDpi;
        private float mMetersToPixelsX;
        private float mMetersToPixelsY;
        private float mXOrigin;
        private float mYOrigin;
        private float mSensorX;
        private float mSensorY;
        private float mHorizontalBound;
        private float mVerticalBound;
        public final ParticleSystem mParticleSystem;
        /*
         * Each of our particle holds its previous and current position, its
         * acceleration. for added realism each particle has its own friction
         * coefficient.
         */



        class Particle extends View {
            private float mPosX = (float) Math.random();
            private float mPosY = (float) Math.random();
            private float mVelX;
            private float mVelY;

            public Particle(Context context) {
                super( context );
            }


            public Particle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);
            }

            public Particle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
                super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
            }

            public Particle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr,
                            int defStyleRes) {
                super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
            }

            public void computePhysics(float sx, float sy, float dT) {

                final float ax = -sx/35;  //viscosity changes
                final float ay = -sy/35;

                mPosX += mVelX * dT + ax * dT * dT ; //original /2
                mPosY += mVelY * dT + ay * dT * dT ;

                mVelX += ax * dT;
                mVelY += ay * dT;
            }


            public void resolveCollisionWithBounds() {
                final float xmax = mHorizontalBound;
                final float ymax = mVerticalBound;
                final float x = mPosX;
                final float y = mPosY;
                if (x > xmax) {
                    mPosX = xmax;
                    mVelX = 0;
                } else if (x < -xmax) {
                    mPosX = -xmax;
                    mVelX = 0;
                }
                if (y > ymax) {
                    mPosY = ymax;
                    mVelY = 0;
                } else if (y < -ymax) {
                    mPosY = -ymax;
                    mVelY = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        /*
         * A particle system is just a collection of particles
         */
        class ParticleSystem {
            static final int NUM_PARTICLES = 1;
            private Particle mBalls[] = new Particle[NUM_PARTICLES];

            ParticleSystem() {
                /*
                 * Initially our particles have no speed or acceleration
                 */
                for (int i = 0; i < mBalls.length; i++) {
                    mBalls[i] = new Particle(getContext());
                    mBalls[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ball);
                    mBalls[i].setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
                    addView(mBalls[i], new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(mDstWidth, mDstHeight));
                }

            }

            /*
             * Update the position of each particle in the system using the
             * Verlet integrator.
             */
            private void updatePositions(float sx, float sy, long timestamp) {
                final long t = timestamp;
                if (mLastT != 0) {
                    final float dT = (float) (t - mLastT) / 1000.f /** (1.0f / 1000000000.0f)*/;
                    final int count = mBalls.length;
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        Particle ball = mBalls[i];
                        ball.computePhysics(sx, sy, dT);
                    }
                }
                mLastT = t;
            }

            /*
             * Performs one iteration of the simulation. First updating the
             * position of all the particles and resolving the constraints and
             * collisions.
             */
            public void update(float sx, float sy, long now) {
                // update the system's positions
                updatePositions(sx, sy, now);

                // We do no more than a limited number of iterations
                final int NUM_MAX_ITERATIONS = 2;  //nyy changed from 10 to 1

                /*
                 * Resolve collisions, each particle is tested against every
                 * other particle for collision. If a collision is detected the
                 * particle is moved away using a virtual spring of infinite
                 * stiffness.
                 */
                boolean more = true;
                final int count = mBalls.length;
                for (int k = 0; k < NUM_MAX_ITERATIONS && more; k++) {
                    more = false;
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        Particle curr = mBalls[i];
                        for (int j = i + 1; j < count; j++) {
                            Particle ball = mBalls[j];
                            float dx = ball.mPosX - curr.mPosX;
                            float dy = ball.mPosY - curr.mPosY;
                            float dd = dx * dx + dy * dy;
                            // Check for collisions
                            if (dd <= sBallDiameter2) {
                                /*
                                 * add a little bit of entropy, after nothing is
                                 * perfect in the universe.
                                 */
                                dx += ((float) Math.random() - 0.01f) * 0.0001f; // 0.05 changed to 0.01 will change the animation pattern and will
                                dy += ((float) Math.random() - 0.01f) * 0.0001f; // 0.0001 chnaged to .001
                                dd = dx * dx + dy * dy;
                                // simulate the spring
                                final float d = (float) Math.sqrt(dd);
                                final float c = (0.5f * (sBallDiameter - d)) / d;
                                final float effectX = dx * c;
                                final float effectY = dy * c;
                                curr.mPosX -= effectX;
                                curr.mPosY -= effectY;
                                ball.mPosX += effectX;
                                ball.mPosY += effectY;
                                more = true;
                            }
                        }
                        curr.resolveCollisionWithBounds();
                    }
                }
            }

            public int getParticleCount() {
                return mBalls.length;
            }

            public float getPosX(int i) {
                return mBalls[i].mPosX;
            }

            public float getPosY(int i) {
                return mBalls[i].mPosY;
            }
        }

        public void startSimulation() {
            /*
             * It is not necessary to get accelerometer events at a very high
             * rate, by using a slower rate (SENSOR_DELAY_UI), we get an
             * automatic low-pass filter, which "extracts" the gravity component
             * of the acceleration. As an added benefit, we use less power and
             * CPU resources.
             */
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);


        }

        public void stopSimulation() {
            mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Accelerometer Disengaged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        }

        public SimulationView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);



            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindow().setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

            mXDpi = metrics.xdpi;
            mYDpi = metrics.ydpi;

            //this will reduce the size of the ball oroginal was 0.0254 changed t 0.0854
            mMetersToPixelsX = mXDpi / 0.00154f;
            mMetersToPixelsY = mYDpi / 0.00154f;

            // rescale the ball so it's about 0.5 cm on screen
            mDstWidth = (int) (sBallDiameter * mMetersToPixelsX * 0.5f);
            mDstHeight = (int) (sBallDiameter * mMetersToPixelsY * 0.5f);
            mParticleSystem = new ParticleSystem();

            Options opts = new Options();
            opts.inDither = true;
            opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            // compute the origin of the screen relative to the origin of
            // the bitmap
            mXOrigin = (w - mDstWidth) * 0.5f;
            mYOrigin = (h - mDstHeight) * 0.5f;
            mHorizontalBound = ((w / mMetersToPixelsX - sBallDiameter) * 0.5f);
            mVerticalBound = ((h / mMetersToPixelsY - sBallDiameter) * 0.5f);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            if (event.sensor.getType() != Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
                return;
            /*
             * record the accelerometer data, the event's timestamp as well as
             * the current time. The latter is needed so we can calculate the
             * "present" time during rendering. In this application, we need to
             * take into account how the screen is rotated with respect to the
             * sensors (which always return data in a coordinate space aligned
             * to with the screen in its native orientation).
             */

            switch (mDisplay.getRotation()) {
                case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                    mSensorX = event.values[0];
                    mSensorY = event.values[1];
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                    mSensorX = -event.values[1];
                    mSensorY = event.values[0];
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                    mSensorX = -event.values[0];
                    mSensorY = -event.values[1];
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                    mSensorX = event.values[1];
                    mSensorY = -event.values[0];
                    break;


            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            /*
             * Compute the new position of our object, based on accelerometer
             * data and present time.
             */
            final ParticleSystem particleSystem = mParticleSystem;
            final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final float sx = mSensorX;
            final float sy = mSensorY;

            particleSystem.update(sx, sy, now);

            final float xc = mXOrigin;
            final float yc = mYOrigin;
            final float xs = mMetersToPixelsX;
            final float ys = mMetersToPixelsY;
            final int count = particleSystem.getParticleCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                /*
                 * We transform the canvas so that the coordinate system matches
                 * the sensors coordinate system with the origin in the center
                 * of the screen and the unit is the meter.
                 */
                final float x = xc + particleSystem.getPosX(i) * xs;
                final float y = yc - particleSystem.getPosY(i) * ys;
                particleSystem.mBalls[i].setTranslationX(x);
                particleSystem.mBalls[i].setTranslationY(y);
            }

            // and make sure to redraw asap
            invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        }
    }
}
```